# WiFi Near Far Interference?

Tags: rf, wifi, interference

I have several ESPWROOM32 based modules that connect to a far away access point with an RSSI of -70 (it's about 50 feet away through several walls) and a close by access point with an RSSI of -30 (about 10 feet away, free space).  Both of the APs are connected to the same subnet via the wired building Ethernet.  The near AP is on channel 4 and the far AP is on channel 0.

I have found that when the ESP32s are connected to the far access point, incoming port connection attempts occasionally time out.  In other testing, similar timeouts were caused by losing the ARP packets that were looking for the ESP32s IP address.

**Is it likely for interference from a nearby AP **on a different channel** to cause packet loss on a connection to a farther away AP?  If so, is there any way to mitigate the interference?**

Comment: Hm, I'd expect the network stack on either your AP or the ESP32 to have a dropped packets counter, and that might be helpful in answering this question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WiFi channel 0 and channel 4 overlap slightly so interference is theoretically possible.
Channel 1, 6 and 11 are the only channel that can be used interference free from one another (you can look at [this picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#/media/File:2.4_GHz_Wi-Fi_channels_(802.11b,g_WLAN).svg) from Wikipedia).

That said, there are many other possible causes of interference e.g. Bluetooth, Microwaves usw. or the AP might just be to far away.

Comment: It looks like moving to channel 6 and lowering the TX power on the closer AP solved the problem.